# How to include folder but excluding some files inside that folder when packaging for serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I want to include node_modules, but exclude the .bin dir, and the .cache and .yarn-integrity files since they take up space on the lambda.

```
        exclude:
            - ./**
            - '!node_modules/**'
            - node_modules/.cache
            - node_modules/.bin
            - node_modules/.yarn-integrity
```

Like wise, I would like to include the 'server' folder, but exclude the tests and eslint config files:

```
        exclude:
            - ./**
            - '!server/**'
            - server/**/*.test.js
            - server/.eslintrc.js
```

But neither work, and the files are not excluded. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the node_modules/ dir while excluding the node_modules/.bin dir like this:

```
package:
   exclude:
     - node_modules/.bin/**
```

By default only these directories are excluded:

```
.git/**
.gitignore
.DS_Store
npm-debug.log
.serverless/**
.serverless_plugins/**
```

So you do not need to specify that `node_modules/` and `server/` are to be included - they will be be default. Just specify which sub-directories inside them you want to exclude.

Source: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/

Comment: I was missing the leading ** glob. Thanks!